# Grails: Store XML values in database

Tags: xml, database, grails, grails-orm

Is there any way to store some properties of domain object in database instead of storing them as strings?

i.e.

```
class Document
{
    String name
    Node value
}
```

instead of:

```
class Document
{
    String name
    String value
}
```

Comment: Which kind of database do you have?

Comment: Currently I have MySQL 5.1 but can change it to PostgreSQL or anything else at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of reading from XML and storing the values in database using grails

Employee info xml file:

```
<employees>
<employee>
<firstname>Marios</firstname>
<deptname>ITdepartment</deptname>
<empid>123</empid>
</employee>
<employee>
<firstname>Ben</firstname>
<deptname>Management</deptname>
<empid>124</empid>
</employee>
</employees>
```

Read and save in Employee table :

```
def Employee = new XmlParser().parse("Your Xml file path")
def set1 = sql.dataSet("Your field name in Xml")
Employee.employee.each {
def firstname = it.firstname.text()
def deptname = it.deptname.text()
def empid = it.empid.text()
set1.add(first_name:firstname,dept_name:deptname,emp_id:empid)
}
```